# In jQuery Autocomplete if user not select a value from available list how can select default input as focused value from available list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete which working good. Now I got another requirement .
when user types  Ame(first few letters in place name) auto complete displaying "America" but if user not selecting from list and typing full name "America" which is a valid place. Here I am validating prompting "Not a valid place" because he not selected from list. Now my requirement is if user not select from the list I want fill the place Name value with first focused value from list.

Answer (score 0):

Use [select event](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select). I mean you can determine how user entered value.

Comment: if user select then i can use select event. select event occurring when user pick an item from list. my requirement is  user searching for place name starting with  "ind" then India, indonesia.. will populate . if user not select also the first value in the list  india should be select in text box.

Comment: Do you mean when I typing "ind" and have choise India, Indonesia etc, then I press backspace and the first from this list should be appear?

Comment: No not like that. first user will enter first few characters then auto suggestions will be populated.Always first element in list will have focus by default. when user not selecting any element from populated list mean he clicked mouse some where else in page then which ever element have focus in previous that element have to be selected in the text box. for example go to http://www.redbus.in/ if type 'chenn' then dont select place name from list click some where else, in this case also chennai place by default it taking . how can i get this feature?

Comment: Try use somsing like [that](http://jsbin.com/ofeyom/4/). But you should check situation when user type and remove value.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a few days trying to get a "perfect" autocomplete feature that only works with existing values...., can pick the id such as customer id , picks data from mysql database instead of provided values(which i think is the main reason a programmer wants).

Just to be clear i am not even sure what some of the lines do. I just picked various pieces of code from many contributors in and out of stack overflow and tested for myself until i got what i wanted.

Plus with the least amount of complexity so that the programmer has a way of being in control of what they are doing.

So here we go.

my page with autocomplete textbox called particulars ie #particulars

### test.php

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css"type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>
 <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>




 <!------ MAKE autocomplete textbox and show all button and id text-box----->

 <input id="particulars"/> 
 <input id="showall" type = "button" Value = "Show all">
 <input style = "background:pink" ; id="creditor"/>
 <script src="particulars.js"></script>

 <!- make your id field (mine here called creditor) hidden!Mine is visible --->
```

You note i have included a file particulars.js
The reason is that i can keep having copies of the file for different autocomplete textboxes as i may need. Because my autocomplete is for the textbox called particulars, my included js file is particulars.js

### particulars.js

```
 var select = false;

 $("#particulars").autocomplete({
 source: function (request, response) {
    $.getJSON("pick_customers.php", {
        term: request.term
    }, response);
},

minLength: 0,
delay: 100,
autoFocus: true,
selectFirst: true,
open: function(event, ui) { if(select) select=false; },

focus: function(event, ui) {
   event.preventDefault();
   //$("#particulars").val(ui.item.label);
   },

select: function(event, ui) { select=true;
                             event.preventDefault();
                             $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                             $('#creditor').val(ui.item.value);
                             $('#showall').focus();
                              return false;
                            }
                                    })

    .blur(function(){
    if(!select) {
            $('#creditor').val("");
            $("#particulars").val($('ul.ui-autocomplete:eq(0) li:first a').text());


    }else {


            }
            });


     // a few additions
     $('#showall').on('click', function () {

                     $('#particulars').val("");
                      $('#creditor').val("");
                     $('#particulars').autocomplete('search' , '');
                     $('#particulars').focus();

                     return false;
                     });


       $('#particulars').on('focus', function () {
                     $('#particulars').autocomplete('search' ,$('#particulars').val());
                     return false;
                     });
```

Now for the php file that is to pick customer names and their ids

### pick_customers.php

```
     <?php

      session_start();


 $term = trim($_GET['term']);

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPassword = "";



   $con = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPassword);
    if (!$con)   { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

  mysql_select_db("myTable", $con);

 $qstring = "SELECT customername,creditor FROM customers WHERE customername LIKE '%".$term."%' order by customername";
 $result = mysql_query($qstring);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $arr['value'] = $row['creditor'];
                    $arr['label'] = $row['customername'];

                    $row_set[] = $arr;

    }

   echo json_encode($row_set);

   mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Apparently the remote data must be encoded json which i understand is not in
the autocomplete documentation. Plus the data for evaluation is passed on as
"term" so that is what to use for querying your returned values for
autocomplete.

I hope this saves someone a tonne of scouring through the internet.
Its the least i can do. 
With gratitude. SO has almost everything on php/js/jquery and a few other matters.